# How can I use jQuery change() with checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm working with Sharepoint and am creating a list with injected Javascript and JQuery. I'm trying to show a text box if the user selects the "Other" option. This option originally came from a dropdown but is now based on checkboxes for multiple selections.

Here's the code based on the dropdown:

```
function TargetAudienceChange(){
  $('select').on('change', function(){
    var TargetAudience = $('select[id*=TargetAudience]').val();
    if (TargetAudience == 'Other (Specify)'){
      $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Other Cultural Awareness')").closest("tr").show();
    }
    else {
      $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Other Cultural Awareness')").closest("tr").hide();
      $('input[id*=OtherTargetAudience]').val("");
    }
  })
}
```

I tried this without success:

```
function TargetAudienceChange(){
  $('checked').on('change', function(){
    var TargetAudience = $('checked[id*=TargetAudience]').val();
    if (TargetAudience == 'Other (Specify)'){
      ...
    }
    else {
      ...
    }
  })
}
```

How can I make this code work for options based on checkboxes that allow multiple selections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with:

```
function TargetAudienceChange(){
  $('input[id*=TargetAudience]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true && $(this).next().text() == 'Other (Specify)'){
      $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Other Cultural Awareness')").closest("tr").show();
    }
    else if ($(this).prop('checked') == false && $(this).next().text() == 'Other (Specify)') {
      $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Other Cultural Awareness')").closest("tr").hide();
      $('input[id*=OtherTargetAudience]').val("");
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This selector:

```
$('checked')
```

Is looking for elements like this:

```
<checked />
```

That's not what a checkbox is.  Take a look at your HTML.  A checkbox is this:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

So you'd use something like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]')
```

or the shorter:

```
$('input:checkbox')
```

---

Same with your other selector:

```
$('checked[id*=TargetAudience]')
```

There's no `<checked />` element, you'd look for elements like:

```
$('input[id*=TargetAudience]')
```

or perhaps:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][id*=TargetAudience]')
```

**Note:** If this selector is targeting more than one element, then `.val()` is probably only going to return the value of the *first* matched element.  How you'd address that depends on whether you want to target a more specific element or if what you actually want is a collection of values from multiple elements.